# how can I change the layout of this material UI form?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a checkout form which I made using material UI looking like this:

[image]

It seems minor but I'd like to change the layout so that First Name and Last Name etc. are all on the same row, looking more like this (but I'm not sure how to go about it):

[image]

Here's the code for my address form component:

```
return (
    <>
      <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
        Shipping address
      </Typography>
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <form
          onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit((data) =>
            test({
              ...data,
              shippingCountry,
              shippingSubdivision,
              shippingOption,
            })
          )}
        >
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <FormInput required name="firstName" label="First name" />
            <FormInput required name="lastName" label="Last name" />
            <FormInput required name="address1" label="Address line 1" />
            <FormInput required name="email" label="Email" />
            <FormInput required name="city" label="City" />
            <FormInput required name="zip" label="Zip / Postal code" />
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <InputLabel>Shipping Country</InputLabel>
              <Select
                value={shippingCountry}
                fullWidth
                onChange={(e) => setShippingCountry(e.target.value)}
              >
                {Object.entries(shippingCountries)
                  .map(([code, name]) => ({ id: code, label: name }))
                  .map((item) => (
                    <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                      {item.label}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
              </Select>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <InputLabel>Shipping Subdivision</InputLabel>
              <Select
                value={shippingSubdivision}
                fullWidth
                onChange={(e) => setShippingSubdivision(e.target.value)}
              >
                {Object.entries(shippingSubdivisions)
                  .map(([code, name]) => ({ id: code, label: name }))
                  .map((item) => (
                    <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                      {item.label}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
              </Select>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <InputLabel>Shipping Options</InputLabel>
              <Select
                value={shippingOption}
                fullWidth
                onChange={(e) => setShippingOption(e.target.value)}
              >
                {shippingOptions
                  .map((sO) => ({
                    id: sO.id,
                    label: `${sO.description} - (${sO.price.formatted_with_symbol})`,
                  }))
                  .map((item) => (
                    <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                      {item.label}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
              </Select>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <br />
          <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
            <Button component={Link} variant="outlined" to="/cart">
              Back to Cart
            </Button>
            <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
              Next
            </Button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </FormProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```

And my custom text field component:

```
import React from "react";
import { TextField, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useFormContext, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

const FormInput = ({ name, label, required }) => {
  const { control } = useFormContext();
  const isError = false;

  return (
    <>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={name}
        render={({ field }) => <TextField fullWidth label={label} required />}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default FormInput;
```

Comment: you have already done it for shipping country and shipping subdivision . You can follow the same . Use `<Grid item />` and use `6` for the breakpoints like sm , md . Since material ui follows 12 column grid giving 6 will give you 2 columns .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're already using Mui Grid so I think you need to place your `<FormInput/>` components within a `<Grid item/>` component.  Like this:

```
<Grid container>
  <Grid container direction="row">
    <Grid item xs={6} sm={6}>
      <FormInput required name="firstName" label="First name" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={6} sm={6}>
      <FormInput required name="lastName" label="Last name" />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>

  ...Another Grid row, and so on...

</Grid>
```